# How to set PhantomJS internal encoding?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, utf-8, phantomjs

I created a simple file named "encoding.js" which contain :

`console.log("é");`

When I run

`node encoding.js` I get `é`.

But when I run `phantomjs encoding.js` I get

`├®`

I'm on 2.1.1 on Windows 10 x64, I tried with 2.5.0 beta2, nothing. Also tried with --output-encoding=utf8 and nothing change.. But node works...

Any idea to force utf8 or to fix the bug ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I solved this issue the following way:

1. Obviously, use UTF-8 as the encoding fo the script file.
2. In the Windows command line interpreter change encoding to UTF-8 by executing `chcp 65001`

After that, running `phantomjs encoding.js` I get `é`

Comment: The `chcp 65001` worked thank you ! But only on 2.1.1. Now when I test it on 2.5.0 beta2, I get `Ã©`. Any idea ?

Comment: Sorry, in my experience 2.5 beta 2 is *too* broken, there's no hope there I'm afraid :) You're better off migrating to [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) which is heavily inspired by PhantomJS (one of its maintainers had even lent a hand to making of puppeteer)

Comment: I see thank you. I already migrated to NightmareJS.. Maybe one day I will try Puppeteer !